# .NET Library for Client/Server application?

Tags: c#, client, chat

I have a plan to write a small "Network manager" for my company using C#. It like a chat application. Please see example bellow:

Ex: Client(C) is manager, Server(S)

```
C: send string "is_process_running x.exe" (check x.exe is running on server pc)
S: check and send to C: "x.exe is running\nPath: 'C:\\windows\system32\x.exe'"
C: "kill_process_with_warning x.exe"
S: Show a message "Administrator detected you 're running a program that disallowed on computer. It will be kill in 10 seconds" and S kill process x.exe. Reply to C: "process killed!"
C: "disconnect"
```

...
...
...

I finding library for that. Please tell me something you know about that.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28VS.71%29.aspx) and [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you wouldn't use WCF?
It may be an overkill for what you described here, but such apps are bound to grow in order to add funcionality.
It does have a great lot of abilities, but here's a [quickstart](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFexample.aspx) guide.